# Why is there no HTMLNavElement type?

Tags: html, types

Why is `HTMLNavElement` not a thing? It seems like most other elements have their own "type" but it seems that `HTMLNavElement` is left out.

I initially thought `HTMLElement`s needed their own type to specify semantic values under the hood.

E.g: `<input type="radio">` inherits the interface of `HTMLInputElement`, which ensures the element gets a `role` of `radio` amongst other things, and a `<div>` inherits the interface of `HTMLDivElement`, which provides no additional functionalities or semantic values.

Comment: `section`, `header`, `footer`, `aside` and other elements use `HTMLElement` as well. I don't know why, but perhaps it's because they have no special behaviour of their own and are purely semantic?

Comment: Ah, interesting.. I was not aware that those elements also did not have their own type

Comment: HTLMDivElement exposes an [`align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement#Properties) property. Elements that don't require any particular property / method won't have their own proto.

Comment: Definitely not ideal for a11y that there is no HTMLNavElement when one likes to implement a custom element based on `<nav>`.

Comment: @silverwind why would you need an HTMLNavElement's interface for this? Just pass `HTMLElement` as the base constructor and build your customized built-in element as usual, with the `extends: "nav"` option.

Comment: Though @silverwind note that Safari doesn't and won't support customized built-ins anyway...

Comment: Right, `extends` seems the way to go. Still getting used to custom elements. Thanks for the Safari info. I will likely go with `role` then: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/navigation_role

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because these elements don't expose any particular method / property.

For instance, they don't have a particular IDL attribute like  `<div>` and their [`align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#Attributes) obsolete IDL attribute which requires a [DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement#Properties) only for `HTMLDivElement` instances:

```js
// HTMLDivElement does expose an align property
console.log(document.querySelector('div').align); // "center"
// HTMLElement doesn't
console.log(document.querySelector('nav').align); // undefined
```

```html
<div align="center"></div>
<nav align="center"></nav>
```

But the semantic isn't brought through the prototype chain anyway.

Comment: Makes sense! My assumption that the various prototypes were also responsible for setting the correct initial semantical values was completely wrong then. Thanks for replying!